# Can we query Library member permission and information about which type of permission member held?

Tags: soql, permissions, permission-sets, contentversion, libraries

Can we query Library(ContentVersion) member permission and information about which type of permission member held ?

- Manage Library
- Add Content
- Add Content on Behalf of Others
- Archive Content
- Delete Content
- Feature Content
- View Comment
- Add Comment
- Modify Comments
- Tag Content

above permission can be seen in content permission , so can we get these library permission programmatically, it term of either by querying or any other  way for a context user or given user id.

I am aware of these permissions what they do for a user.

Comment: Ankuli that's not much details to go on or to know what you've already tried or looked at.  Understand that more info can make your question and answers received more specific and likely to be useful. Selecting appropriate tags will also help attract the right knowledgeable people to the question, i've gone ahead and updated those already.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke sure from next time.

Comment: You haven't had a response in 2 days, I would not wait until next time. Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:  **No**

It is discussed in further detail [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008zeaIAA).

Comment: I know this is a crap answer, but I wasted about a hour looking for a definitive yes or no.  Hopefully this will help someone else from doing the same.